# How do I get my selected items out of the database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I wrote this code but it doesn't work

```
{
  "name": "ehsan",
  "test": [
    {
      "$oid": "6320ea167283ccc7c86cd8e6"
    },
    {
      "$oid": "6320ea1f7283ccc7c86cd8eb"
    },
  ],
}

{
  "item": "dsfd",
  "item2": "dsdsdsds",
}
```

I want to extract the cases of my evolution from the test object

```
let tests = await this.Tests.find({
  _id: { $in: result["test"].find().select("item") },
});
```

Comment: Give me some dummy data based on your data

Comment: What is `result["test"]` equal to?